# Adding a sub collection of new object and my new object into the database with Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The method is really simple and I don't see what am I missing...

```
 public int SaveEvent(Data.Models.Event evnt)
    {
        db.Events.Add(evnt);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return evnt.EventId;
    }
```

here is the object declaration:

```
   public class Event
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EventTag> EventTags { get; set; }
    }
```

The `evnt` object contains a property name `EventTags` that contains 6 new elements.
The `evnt` is inserted in the database but not the `EventTag`... any idea ? no error nothing. just the `EventTag` are not added...

```
public class EventDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public DbSet<EventTag> EventTags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the value:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the EventTags are not being added to the database you may need to manually specify the EntityState for each tag.

```
public int SaveEvent(Data.Models.Event evnt)
{

    foreach(var tag in evnt.EventTags) 
    {
       db.Entry(tag).State = EntityState.Added; 
    }

    db.Events.Add(evnt);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return evnt.EventId;
}
```

You might also want to update your class definition and set the EventTags property as `virtual`.

```
 public class Event
 {
     public int EventId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<EventTag> EventTags { get; set; }
 }
```

In your screenshot it looks like the tags are loading, but not the Location property on the tags. If that's the case, then make sure to set the Location property to `virtual` as well.

Comment: Actually what I've read is virtual is for lazy loading, but I don't want to lazy load those. I may be wrong

Comment: The manual entry did work, but I don't understand why? is it possible to do it without it ? I've check the state of the tag before setting it and it was "unknown".

Comment: If you don't want to use lazy loading then you can manually load the records.  Here's a good [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) that covers the process.  That being said, lazy loading's not always a bad thing.  You might do some benchmarking to make sure your performance is really affected before deciding against it.

Comment: Unfortunately, getting the Entity Framework to recognize the state of child objects sometimes requires using the db.Entry() approach.

Comment: Well it did work. too bad I have to do it manually. but Thank you !

Comment: FYI, this is something we're trying to improve in EF7. See our [design meeting notes](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes:-December-4,-2014#graph-behaviors).

Comment: @bricelam - Glad to hear it.

Comment: @bricelam thanks for the info, just read all the design meeting, very interesting stuff. Continue the good work and hoping that EF7 will be in RC state this summer since I intend to go in production in august :).